# Узнать, откуда зашли в метод, не используя IDE

Tags: java

Есть ли возможность узнать, откуда мы попали в метод?

```
class TargetClass{
    public final void targetMethod() {
        //Узнать от куда мы сюда попали, с FromA или с FromB
    }
}

class FromA{
    targetClassObj.targetMethod()
}

class FromB{
    targetClassObj.targetMethod()
}
```

Возможности использовать дебагер IDE к сожалению нету.
Возможно есть какие-то возможности для подобного действия?

Comment: Можно теоретически кинуть Exception, и получить стактрейс: 
try
{
   throw new Exception("");
}

catch( Exception e ) {
 e.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() + 
"." +
e.getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + 
 "()!" );
}

Но возможно есть более лучшее решение

Comment: Опишите реальню задачу

Comment: Если внутри `public`-метода Вам надо знать, кто его вызвал, то с Вашим кодом явно что-то не так!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать [getStackTrace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29) потока:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```